# Making a checkbox in Qt UI a checked/unchecked based on a variable

Tags: c++, qt

As the title says I have trouble making a checkbox depend on my code. I know how to make it checked/unchecked via the UI window menu when searching through the QAbstractButton parent class of the check box. How do I invoke and change it in my code?

Comment: your question is unclear, maybe if you provide a [mcve] we could understand.

Comment: That is not the way to learn how to program in Qt. The library has one of the best API documentations I have ever read, as well as plenty of tutorials and examples. One should start there first.

Comment: I am not accessing it via code. I am CLICKING stuff in the UI window (you know, the one where you drag and drop everything). I Have checked the documentation and even though there is information on how to change the value with a funtion in QAbstractButton I don't know how to access this object that derives from QAbstractButton. The answer bellow suggests to call the setChecked function via the name "checkbox" but what if I have multiple check boxes? How does the name checkbox call the one I intend?

Comment: Once again, if you watch a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3EWVLPAoeA), it would be much easier for you to grasp the idea of how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Call [`checkbox->setChecked(bool)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop).

Comment: how do I know which checkbox to call if i have multiple checkboxes?

Comment: @ХристоИванов This is a surprsing question. If you change the state of a checkbox interactively - how do you know which corresponding variable to update? You should've checkboxes for corresponding variables (or anything else representing states of your underlying data model in a certain way) which you have to consider.

Comment: You give them meaningful names in the designer as opposed to the automatically generated names like `checkbox1` and `checkbox2`.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question, however I found an answer: I can access the checkbox via the ui pointer. ui->checkbox->setChecked(bool). I have tried typing only checkbox->setChecked(bool) and checkbox wasn't declared.